# Question page not loading

Tags: support, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

Today as usually I have found in my google reader new set of questions. One of them had really strange preview as the following was displayed as subject:

> Write an algorithm ( It is recommend that you use genetic) to improve at least one small tiny point. For example, minimize the cost, or reduce delay or reduce error rate or whatever you feel that is good for the design andImplement a program or ru [closed]

Despite of having poor formatting I tried to read the question but is not loading for me in browser while I can still see preview in reader. When I tried to load question in browser 'Page not found' was displayed.
Even if question is closed (as last part of subject suggest) should I get 'Page Not Found'? Or if the question was deleted shouldn't this information be provided instead of 'Page Not Found'?

[Link to question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804692/write-an-algorithm-it-is-recommend-that-you-use-genetic-to-improve-at-least)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Damn! In that case I'm not sure if it is handled properly. Lots of users (those before 10K rep) are presented 'Page Not Found' which is not the same as 'Page deleted by administrator' and definitely not like 'Page deleted by administrator - repeated question. For original question refer to [URL]'. Besides couldn't it be just merged questions into one question page?

Comment: Deleted is deleted... actually, merging makes it *harder* to find, as then it **really** doesn't exist (even admins can't see it).

Comment: well.. yeah... if it only said 'deleted'. I find it disturbing that I have feed with link to So and I get message page not found... If it would say 'Deleted' I would know that I won't read this question. When it says Page not found I start to wonder why? What have I done wrong that page is not found? Is link broken? Maybe my rss reader broke the link? Maybe there are characters in link that make it impossible to display the page? I'm asking here and there, trying to analyze/troubleshoot the problem wasting mine and SO team time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was deleted by an admin; the same user had posted the same question multiple times in succession, attracting *lots* of negative attention.

If you have 10k rep you can see it still. But a "page not found" is reasonable for something that isn't *really* there any more.